# Typescript error TS1005: ';' expected. TS v1.8.10

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs

I am receiving the following error when trying to compile a typescript file. This is more first time playing with typescript so honestly I have no idea on what I am doing wrong...

```
Running "ts:default" (ts) task
Compiling...
### Fast Compile >>src/FileProcessor.ts
Using tsc v1.8.10
src/FileProcessor.ts(1,21): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

I am compiling it with "grunt-ts" using the following grunt task...

```
ts: {
  default: {
    src: ['src/**/*.ts'],
    outDir: 'lib/',
    options: {
      module: 'commonjs'
    }
  }
},
```

Below is my typescript file

```
import path = module('path');

console.log(path.join('test', 'test2'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch

```
import path = module('path');
```

to

```
import path = require('path');
```

Comment: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'.    -    Now getting this... path is a default node module though?

Comment: Have you imported the path module (either add to your package.json file or use npm install --save-dev path)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html - Path comes with Node.js installation - Normal es5 execution you can just require it locally?

Comment: You need a definition for node.d.ts. Either download directly from DefinitelyTyped or use the typings tool to install it (the latter is better as you'll need it for other dependencies).